# Module for getting what is visible from user's webcam

Tags: 7

I need a module that allows users to show what is visible from their webcam. 
Is there a module that can do this?

Comment: I've done the best I can with the English, but for me this question still makes no sense.  Can you expand on what you are trying to achieve?  It sounds to me like you want to show the user the output from his/her webcam in the node body?

Comment: yes i want to registered user to open his camera (output in a node) to let the other users to show him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is exactly what you want at the moment, but the following module might help you on your way:

[Webcam field](http://drupal.org/project/webcam) - This is still in development

> Webcam field provides dynamically updating webcam image fields. This
>   module is compatible with Colorbox.

[Videochat](http://drupal.org/project/videochat) - Has no recommended release, although seems to have a full 3.6 version

> The Video Chat module adds a fully hosted free video chat to a Drupal
>   website. The chat application and video hosting are courtesy of
>   Camamba and ad-supported. We hope it provides an alternative to all
>   the payware chat modules out there.

[Media: Webcam](http://drupal.org/project/media_webcam) - This is in beta

> This project (still under active development) will add a Webcam
>   capture tool for video and images to FileField. Video requires a Red5
>   or Flash Media server to also be available; documentation for this
>   coming soon enough.

[Video conference](http://drupal.org/project/vconf) - This requires some further set up of server components, but if you want live video streaming I should imagine you're aware that you will most likely need a [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) protocol set up.

> VideoWhisper Video Conference is a modern web based multiple way video
>   chat and real time file sharing tool. It can be used stand alone or
>   integrated as extra feature to existing sites. Internet based video
>   conference software is great for bringing physically distant people
>   together in meetings, trainings, conferences, live events, recruiting,
>   consultations, coaching and of course casual community chat.

**Paid solution**

[AVChat](http://avchat.net/integrations/drupal)

This comes at a price of $285 plus $49 for the Drupal module

Comment: This seems like a great answer. Just one extra item worth mentioning that you could incorporate into your answer: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mdryan/2096387 which uses modern javascript/html to create a new file field input formatter.